# Would a phone app based DHT network be practical?

Tags: android, python, node.js, p2p, dht

I would like to implement a DHT network, similar to the one used in Bittorrent but instead of being used to find peer lists for Bittorrent swarms, it will be used for finding peer lists for different network shards. The thing is that the primary node type in the DHT network will be a mobile phone app and they will likely only be online for a very short amount of time (5 minutes) before they turn off. Is this practical or would the fact that the nodes are not very long lasting make the network to unstable and unusable?

Could you also provide links to any Python or Node.JS libraries that could assist in this?

Thanks and sorry if this question is too in-specific or not formatted correctly.
Let me know and I will fix it, as this is my first time asking a question here!

Comment: Phone internet providers often don't allow "servers" running on client devices. DHT does not work very well if other peers cannot connect to your phone directly.

Comment: @C.Yduqoli Is it absolutely required that a node in a p2p network be a "server" (have open ports to the public internet) or can they receive connections without being a sever?  I know that IPFS full nodes are possible to run on mobile devices, how do they work if mobile phones do not allow for p2p networking?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe a certain number of servers needs to be available in the network. These can facilitate connections between non-server nodes.
But my knowledge about phone networks like 3G is limited. And I don't know how IPFS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DHTs in ad-hoc networks is achievable, but requires a lot of redundancy and recovery for nodes joining/leaving regularly. Kadence written in nodejs, and is a full implementation of Kademlia DHT system.

https://gitlab.com/kadence/kadence